# What does the XP utility CProfile do?

Tags: windows-xp

I expanded i386 off an XP Pro SP3 CD, and I'm looking into all the .exe's in the folder because I'm curious. (I'm a PC technician, and good new utilities are hard to come by.) When I saw a `CProfile.exe` I thought it was create profile.

Looked at the version information "FileDescription", "Clean Profile Utility"

I decided to look it up, to see if it's any good / what it does:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_cprofile.mspx

"Cleans profile of wasted space"

Running the tool on a virtual XP installation (which by the way is not in the Windows folder-- I had to manually expand it from the CD), it seems to loop through all the profiles in the registry, check if they are in use, and then just process the registry.

**Does anyone know what CProfile.exe does or if it's useful?**